# Stubbing seneca.act with sinon results in timeout

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

I have a unit under test, specifically I'm trying to test the `invoke` property of the class. Since it depends on `seneca` I choose to use `sinon.stub` for it.

But when I run the test I notice it only getting timed out

```
Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

Meaning it is not reaching `svc.then()` statement where I call `done()`

My problem is if I'm using `stub.yields` correctly to return a `stub.resolves`
I also tried checking if the stub called `senecaStub.called` and it did return `true`

// **unit under test**

```js
const seneca = require('seneca')

class Service {
  constructor() {
    let senecaBus = seneca()
    // ... some seneca opt config

    this.invoke = (pattern, opts) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        senecaBus.act(pattern, {opts}, function (err, res) {
          if (err) reject(err)
          resolve(resp)
        })
      })
    }
  }
module.exports = Service
```

**// tests**

```js
global.Promise = require('bluebird') 
const Svc = require('./')

const sinon = require('sinon')
const seneca = require('seneca')

describe(`Service Test`, function () {
  let svc = null
  let sandbox = null
  let senecaStub = null
      
  before(function () {
    sandbox = sinon.createSandbox()

    senecaStub = sandbox.stub(seneca.test(), 'act')
      .usingPromise(global.Promise)

    svc = new Svc()
  })

  after(function () {
    sandbox.restore()
  })
      
  it(`should test invoke`, function (done) {
    // Arrange
    senecaStub
      .yields(null, sandbox.stub().resolves('stub promise resolved'))

    // Act
    svc.invoke('a:1', {}).then(result => {
      // doesn't reach here
      console.log(`promise resolved`, result)
      done()
    }).catch(error => {
      // doesn't reach here as well
      console.log(`had an error`, error)
      done()
    })
    console.log(`stub called: `, senecaStub.called) // prints stub called: true
  })
})
```